# Setuptools installation in Jython

Tags: python, jython, windows-7-x64, setuptools

Latest Jython standalone (2.7 final), latest setuptools:

```
C:\projects_intellij\test_jython>jython.bat ez_setup.py

C:\projects_intellij\test_jython>java -jar "C:\projects_intellij\test_jython\jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar" ez_setup.py
Extracting in C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpt_1anc
Now working in C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpt_1anc\setuptools-21.2.2
Installing Setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ez_setup.py", line 425, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "ez_setup.py", line 422, in main
    return _install(archive, _build_install_args(options))
  File "ez_setup.py", line 59, in _install
    if not _python_cmd('setup.py', 'install', *install_args):
  File "ez_setup.py", line 51, in _python_cmd
    return subprocess.call(args) == 0
  File "C:\projects_intellij\test_jython\jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", line 500, in call
  File "C:\projects_intellij\test_jython\jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", line 830, in __init__
  File "C:\projects_intellij\test_jython\jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
TypeError: args must contain only strings
```

Is there a way to install this using Jython? Should I have used Jython installed by the installer instead of standalone?

Platform: Win 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you should have.

It looks like a version problem.

Same here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/jython/mailman/jython-users/thread/CAOhO%3DaNmNL6xeKES2JXPkg%2BP3OTBxJCESNA0YtfLVX1L1fv85w@mail.gmail.com/